# Install own projects as dependency | module name issue

Tags: python, pip

I have multiple projects I am working on several libraries and several clients which require these libraries as dependencies.

### **library** structure

```
$ pwd
~/Projects/library

$ tree
.
├── api.py
├── __init__.py
└── setup.py

$ cat api.py
import requests

# ...

def process(data):
    for record in data:
        print(f"Processing {record}")

$ cat __init__.py
from .api import process

$ cat setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='my_library',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'requests',
    ],
)
```

I then pushed the code to my private github repo, and now want to install it as a dependency of **client**

### **client** structure

```
$ pwd
~/Projects/client

$ tree -a -L 1
.
├── .venv
└── client.py

$ cat client.py
from my_library import process

data = list(range(5))
process(data)

$ . .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/USER/library.git
...
Installing collected packages: idna, certifi, urllib3, chardet, requests, my-library
  Running setup.py install for my-library ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 my-library-1.0.0 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.3

$ python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_library import process
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_library'
```

A point that I realized and am thinking it might be related to the question;

- The directory (and repo) are named `library` (single word)
- In `setup.py` the name is `my_library` (`name='my_library'`) (separated by an underscore)
- `pip freeze` shows it as `my-library==1.0.0` (separated with a hyphen)

Comment: maybe the problem is in the structure of your project, you can improve your question with a [MRE]

Comment: edited my post, I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused between the project name and package/ module name.

Python import system doesn't care about the project name, only pip does.

Python cares about packages and modules but your project doesn't have packages therefore find_packages() doesn't add nothing to your folder.

What you should do is:

1. Create a folder named my_library under the project folder.
2. Put __init__.py on this folder
3. Put you python modules in this folder.
4. Remove the __init__.py from your project folder.

More info [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject?files=1)

Comment: Thanks, yup that fixed my issue

Comment: Just a small question, since I named my project `my_library` in `setup.py` why does `pip freeze` show `my-library` with a hyphen?

Comment: pip converts underscore names to dashed names. it is called "safe names". This lies back many years ago. I am not sure why, but assume the motivation was to standardize the package names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great help!